# Change Color and text of items in cell in collectionView

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I want change color of circleView and text in label in cell in CollectionView using function.

Class of my Cell:

```
class CustomCell: UICollectionViewCell {

override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupViews()
    }

var timerLabel:UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = "5"
        label.frame = CGRect(x: 200, y: 10, width: 60, height: 60)
        label.backgroundColor = .white
        label.textAlignment =  NSTextAlignment.center

        return label
    }()

var circleView: UIView = {
        let circleView = UIView()
        circleView.frame = CGRect(x: 100, y: 10, width: 60, height: 60)
        circleView.backgroundColor = .red
        circleView.layer.cornerRadius = 30
        circleView.layer.masksToBounds = true

        return circleView
    }()

func setupViews() {
        backgroundColor = .white
        addSubview(timerLabel)
        addSubview(circleView)
    }

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setupViews()
    }
}
```

Create CollectionView in VC:

```
func collectionViewSet() {
        collectionView?.frame.size.height = (view.frame.height / 100) * 70
        collectionView?.backgroundColor = .white
        collectionView?.register(CustomCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellId)
    }

//-------------- (CollectionView Configure) -------------------

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 5
    }

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width:view.frame.width ,height: collectionView.frame.height / 6)
    }

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId , for: indexPath)
        customCell.tag = indexPath.row + 1

        return cell
}
```

And in my created func for example setColor() i want generate ranodm color (by UIColor) for CircleView and generate random number for TimerLable but only  in one cell. For next cell I want generate another color and number. Is there any way to do that, i was trying use indexPath.row and func didselectedItemForindexPath but it didn't works at all. Maybe I did something wrong.

Comment: Share the ss of your output

Comment: But output of what? I do not use storyboard

Comment: Output on simulator when you run your code

Answer (score 1):

Ok I have found an answer. I post my code if someone will have similar problem :)

```
 for x in 0...4{
        let indexPath = IndexPath(row: x, section: 0)
        guard let cell = collectionView?.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? CustomCell else {
            return
        }

        cell.circleView.backgroundColor = .blue
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many, many examples of generating random colors and numbers out there - a quick search and you'll have plenty to choose from.

Once you've picked a couple, change your `cellForItemAt` function to:

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId , for: indexPath)
        customCell.tag = indexPath.row + 1

        let randColor = myRandomColorFunc()
        let randNumber = myRandomNumberFunc()

        customCell.circleView.backgroundColor = randColor
        customCell.timerLabel.text = "\(randNumber)"

        return cell
}
```

Comment: Ok great it's work but it's work "on load". I want it will only pick color and number when I called this function (for example via button). It's possible?

Comment: Not sure what you mean... Do you want to change the Cell's "circleView backgroundColor" and the "timerLabel text" to random color/number when you tap on the Cell? Or you have a button somewhere and you want to reload the CollectionView with new random colors and numbers? Try to *clearly* explain what you want to do...

Comment: This secound situation, i have a button